# your emacs does not come with xwidget support... (Windows 10)

Tags: microsoft-windows, display, web-browser

Just unzipped and started using Emacs 25.1, hoping to get a browser running in emacs.  The instructions I found had me enter

```
"M-x xwidget-webkit-browse-url"
```

And then I'm asked to complete a command like this:

```
http://editing.
```

Which I do with some random URL -- then I'm told that:

```
Your emacs did not compile with xwidget support.
```

Can anyone give me some simple instructions to follow to fix this?  (hopefully this isn't too involved...)

Comment: I added an article in my answer suggested by @M.W. about compiling Emacs with Xwidgets via Cygwin; you might want to look at it if you're still interested in using Xwidgets on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use Emacs on Windows, nor do I use xwidgets, but I do know that Emacs has to be compiled with xwidgets (since some of its stuff is written in C) for it to work. Taking a cursory look at the `configure` options for Emacs, I see a particular option for compiling Emacs with xwidgets:

```
--with-xwidgets         enable use of some gtk widgets in Emacs buffers
                          (requires gtk3)
```

I'm not sure how you would compile Emacs like this on Windows, but my first guess would be to use Cygwin or something similar.

EDIT:

[Here's an article about compiling Emacs with Xwidgets support on Windows via Cygwin](https://tuhdo.github.io/setup-emacs-windows.html), courtesy of [M.W.](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/13940/m-w) I'll copy it here for convenience and to circumvent link rot:

---

## Setup Emacs with PDF Tools and Xwidgets web browser on Windows

Installation instructions:

### Prerequisite

- Download `Cywing` setup from [Cygwin's Install page](https://cygwin.com/install.html).
- If you want only the PDF reader, you can install the Emacs shipped by
  Cygwin. However, if you also want the web browser, then you need to
  compile your own Emacs 25 from source.

### With PDF reader

[DEMO](https://tuhdo.github.io/static/setup-emacs-windows/pdf_tools_windows_latex.gif) (Notice how I press some text in PDF file and Latex buffer jumps to corresponding automatically).

First, don’t use MELPA; you must install pdf-tools manually from this repository. Then, you need to install Cygwin. The following dependencies are needed:

If you don't plan to use Xwidget browser, just install Emacs from Cygwin:

- emacs-w32 (Editors category)

Then install the tool chain for PDF Tools:

- make (**Devel** category)
- gcc-core (**Devel** category)
- gcc-g++ (**Devel** category)
- autoconf (**Devel** category)
- automake (**Devel** category)
- perl (**Perl** category)

Then install Poppler development library:

- libpoppler-devel (**Lib** category)
- libpoppler-glib-devel (**Lib** category)

Just type the dependency name above and click to choose. For example, enter libpoppler-devel into the search box.

After all dependencies installed, clone `pdf-tools`:

```
git clone https://github.com/politza/pdf-tools
```

Then, go into pdf-tools directory and build it:

```
make
```

When the compilation is done, from your Cygwin Terminal, copy the file `server/epdfinfo.exe` into `/usr/bin/`:

```
cp server/epdfinfo.exe /usr/bin/
```

Then, also within **Cygwin**, run **emacs** command. Within Emacs, run the Emacs command:

- `M-x package-install-file`
- Press `RET`
- Select pdf-tools-${VERSION}.tar RET (the tar file is in your
  repository).
- Finally, run pdf-tools-install and enjoy. Here is the configuration
  you can put in your init file:

  (pdf-tools-install)
  (setq pdf-info-epdfinfo-program "/usr/bin/epdfinfo.exe")

### With Xwidgets browser

[DEMO](https://tuhdo.github.io/static/setup-emacs-windows/emacs_xwidgets_windows.png)

Development libraries for building Emacs that supports Xwidgets:

- libgif-devel (**Graphics** category)
- libtiff-devel (**Lib** category)
- libjpeg-devel (**Devel** category)
- libxpm-devel (**Devel** category)
- libgnutls-devel (**Devel** category)
- libpng-devel (**Devel** category)
- libncurses-devel (**Lib** category)
- libgtk3-drivel (**Lib** category)
- libwebkitgtk3.0-devel (**Lib** category)

Then, install X11 server for displaying Emacs:

- xorg-server (**X11** category)
- xinit (**X11** category)

Then, open Cygwin terminal and compile Emacs:

```
./configure --with-xwidgets
make
make install
```

Finally, set your display:

```
echo "export DISPLAY=:0.0" >> .bash_profile
```

Then, from your Start Menu, open the X server:

[image: Xserver example]

Then, run your compiled Emacs 25 from Cygwin terminal:

```
emacs
```

Comment: https://tuhdo.github.io/setup-emacs-windows.html has step-by-step instructions to compile Emacs with XWidget (and PDF) support using the Cygwin toolchain and libraries.

Comment: @M.W. Ok, great. I'll edit my answer to contain that article.